# Vault APPROLE Authentication Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config

I was using vault to login via curl to get a new token so far. This works as expected:

```
curl -k     --request POST     --data '{"role_id":"myrole","secret_id":"mysecret"}'     https://<host>:<port>/vault/v1/auth/approle/login
```

Now I'd like to do the same in spring cloud with the following bootstrap.yml:

```
spring.cloud.vault:
uri: https://<host>:<port>
authentication: APPROLE
app-role:
    role-id: myrole
    secret-id: mysecret
```

But this isn't working and the application throws the following exception on startup:

```
2018-09-06 07:28:57.054  INFO 8804 --- [           main] o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager     : Scheduling Token renewal
2018-09-06 07:28:57.144  WARN 8804 --- [           main] LeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='secret/application', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Status 403 secret/application: permission denied

    org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 secret/application: permission denied
```

Comment: According to the error message, it's the access to `https://<host>:<port>/vault/v1/secret/application` that fails. The login seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding
        app-role-path: approle

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22240671)